# nonhomogenous BVP ODE solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem

What are the steps necessary to solve the following boundary value problem?
$$
y''(x) - y'(x) + y(x) = \delta (x)
$$
$$
y(-1) = 1, y(1) = 1
$$
I do not need an exact solution for that problem, rather a lists of steps that can be applied to solve these kind of ODEs

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Find all homogeneous solutions satisfying the left boundary conditions,
2. ... the right ...,
3. select one of each so that the combination is continuous and the derivative jumps up by $1$ at $x=0$.

Comment: Thanks! But why is it the first derivative that must have a jump?

Comment: So that the second derivative, the first derivative of the jump, produces the Dirac delta pulse.

Answer (score 0):

*N.B: The general solution for a non-homogeneous second order differential equation is*;
$$y(x) = y_p(x) + y_c(x)$$

**First Step**:
Find the homogeneous general solution, otherwise known as the complimentary equation. You replace your right hand function, for $0$. In your case, $y''(x) - y'(x) + y(x) = 0$. This will be your $y_c(x)$.

**Second Step**:
You have to now find a particular solution, $y_p(x)$. You have to see how your right hand function, $\delta (x)$; when you take the second derivative, then minus the first derivative and add the original function, you get your right hand solution. Pick a general solution your right hand sided function could be, this varies cases to case. With this general solution of your right hand function, plug it into $y''(x) - y'(x) + y(x)$ (in your case). This will allow you to find $y_p(x)$.

**Third Step**:
Add your $y_p(x)$ and $y_c(x)$ to get your ODE solution.

**Fourth Step**:
Plug in your boundary conditions for $y(x)$, to find the particular solution for $y(x)$.

Hope this is clear and helps.

Comment: That is what I was trying. Unfortunately it does not work in this case...

Comment: Maybe using the "Method of Variation of Parameters" - https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Calculus/Book%3A_Calculus_(OpenStax)/17%3A_Second-Order_Differential_Equations/17.2%3A_Nonhomogeneous_Linear_Equations#:~:text=To%20solve%20a%20nonhomogeneous%20linear,solution%20to%20the%20nonhomogeneous%20equation.&text=the%20complementary%20equation.-,Then%2C%20the%20general%20solution%20to%20the%20nonhomogeneous%20equation%20is%20given,%2Byp(x).